# Populate table row on tree item click using SWT

Tags: java, swt, jface

Is there anyway to pouplate table row after clicking Tree Item.?I don't want to use SWT/Jface TreeTableViewer. Suppose i have Tree with some tree items like cosmetics, Powder. When i click on cosmetic, related value should be populated in table.

Comment: Just add a `SelectionListener` to the tree which adds a new row to the table.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

    final Tree tree = new Tree(shell, SWT.SINGLE);
    tree.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    /* initialize columns */

    TreeItem cosmetics = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE);
    cosmetics.setText(0, "cosmetics");
    /* other text */

    TreeItem powder= new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE);
    powder.setText(0, "powder");
    /* other text */


    /* add selection listener to add children */
    tree.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            /* get selection */
            TreeItem[] items = tree.getSelection();

            if(items.length > 0)
            {
                String parent = items[0].getText();
                System.out.println(parent);

                /* add new child */
                TreeItem newItem = new TreeItem(items[0], SWT.NONE);
                newItem.setText(0, "new Item, parent: " + parent);

                /* Expand parent */
                items[0].setExpanded(true);
            }
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

It will add a new child to every `TreeItem` you click on.

Comment: Thanks Bazz. But i need to populate tableviewer on click on any tree item. Since i can't attach screenshot i am providing u link so that you can add image. http://eaddress.co.kr/sbstory/01basicset/goodspricepage.asp

Comment: @user1925819 I still don't see what you mean. Can you explain in more detail what exactly it is that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: as per link i provided eaddress.co.kr/sbstory/01basicset/goodspricepage.asp, When i click on tree item "Conditioner current", the related values will be displayed in table viewer

Comment: @user1925819 When I click on "conditioner current" nothing happens. Looks like a static page to me. You will have to explain _in detail_ what's not working for you. Is it just the automatic expanding of nodes?

Comment: Yes it is static page. "conditioner current" is one of the node in Tree. When i click on node the related result will be displayed in tableviewer. (itz like select productname, size,color, price from item where Item.classificationname='conditioner current'). Also as you said it is automatic expanding.

Comment: Just add this line at the end of the listener: `items[0].setExpanded(true);`. This will take care of the expanding. If this still isn't what you want you will have to explain **in detail** what you want...

Comment: Let me give you scenario. As you see in screenshot... I have a separate tree component which has item classification and separate table component. When i click on any of the item classification item , related product details should be populated in table for that particular tree item. The values i get is from DB for tree as well as table. Tree is dynamic is nature.

Comment: That's nice, but you can do all that with the code I provided. I'm not going to code all of it for you. You should be able to figure it out yourself now.

Comment: Thanks Baz. I don't have issue with tree structure.I will try my best to get solution :)

Comment: @user1925819 Yeah, do that and if you have any specific problems, come back and ask for help again.

Comment: @user1925819 Please don't post code in comments. If you found the solution, post it as an answer, if you want to add more information to your question, edit your question...

Answer (score 0):

i have got the solution

```
TreeViewer treeViewer= new TreeViewer(comp);
final TableViewer viewer= new TableViewer(comp1, SWT.BORDER);
treeViewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener()
{
    public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) 
{ 
    IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) event.getSelection(); 
    Object obj= selection.getFirstElement();
    viewer.setInput(obj);
 } 
});
    }
```